# Dynamically Adjust Currency On Report Based On User(Manager)?

Tags: apex, reporting, multi-currency, reports-api

I would like the currency on a report to dynamically change depending on the current user running the report in a multi-currency enabled org. Is there a way to accomplish this? I've looked around online for ideas and while there is a similar post in the Ideas forum of the dev boards, I haven't had much success.

As an alternative I am looking at creating a different report for each currency in question but would like a cleaner solution.

Comment: Your title says manager, your post says user. Which one is it? I always thought that reports already changed based on the user itself...

Comment: I would like the manager to see a report which would include subordinates Opportunity numbers (which could be in EUR, etc) in that managers' regions' currency, which would be USD for example. USD may not necessarily be the "global" currency of the org in this example. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're describing Salesforce's default behavior.

> Amounts in reports are shown in their original currencies, but can be
>   displayed in any active currency. You can change the currency used for
>   report totals by selecting a currency from Show | Currencies. **The**
>   **default value is your personal currency.** For any amount, you can
>   choose to display the Converted column—for example, Annual Revenue
>   Converted—which shows amounts in the currency you select.

Emphasis added is mine

Documentation is [here](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=admin_currency.htm&language=en_US)